# The function works but is invisible. How?

Tags: r

Is there any possibility to make a function invisible in the package and private use?

Look at library frbs, at the function `frbs.fit`:

```
library(frbs)
edit(frbs)
```

in the function we got a function called `setDefaultParametersIfMissing`. But where is this defined? There is no visible function called like this in the package and no visible in the function `frbs.fit`!

How it is possible and how to get definition of this missing function?

Comment: just don't `export` the function

Comment: Try `frbs:::setDefaultParametersIfMissing` or `getAnywhere(setDefaultParametersIfMissing)`

Comment: thank you thank you